# Logging in with php, then executing a script

Tags: php, coldfusion

I have been requested to execute a script located in another server, the script can be executed via the browser easily (it has a small log in page, and then by visiting the url the script (in .cfm) is executed)

How can I do this with PHP? I'm thinking on using curl_exec to visit the page, but I don't know how I can pass the log in.. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible; you can pass the login very easily by submitting normal POST data to the form.  I assume you have a name/password you can use, so you can just pass these with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

If you need to visit an *additional* URL after logging in, you need the SID either from the effective URL or more stably from the cookie.

On the initial `curl_exec` set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to any blank file (it can be a tmp file).  On subsequent `curl_exec`, set the URL appropriately and set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to this same file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2).

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new HTTP_Request2('http://Your site/', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
// This will set credentials for Digest auth
$request->setAuth('user', 'password', HTTP_Request2::AUTH_DIGEST);

try {

    $response = $request->send();
    if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
        echo $response->getBody();
    } else {
        echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
         $response->getReasonPhrase();
    }
} catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

`$request->setAuth` is the key method here.